# Called 112 (emergency) but no record in call log?

Tags: 8.0-oreo, call-history

Last week I called 112 for an emergency. Later I saw that this call was not logged. In the past these calls were logged. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: guesswork: it only appears in call logs when screen is unlocked and called from regular dialer app